# How to remove an empty string from array

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string

My input string is

```
String s = ",1,,2, ,3,4,5,,6";
String[] array = s.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Now I am getting this output

```
[, 1, , 2,  , 3, 4, 5, , 6]
```

But the expected output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Make your input nicer. This isn't a real life scenario I hope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
s.replaceAll("^[, ]+", "").split("[, ]+");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this enhanced regex to avoid empty match:

```
s.replaceFirst("^( *, *)+", "").split("(, *)+");
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks now i am getting [,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. The first element is empty string.

Comment: To remove the leading comma's, I would: `"^ *,+"`.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Corrected it.

Comment: Indeed. Even better than I thought of. +1

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the task. First, you need to trim any commas at the beginning or end.

Afterwards, you can split the String using `\s*,[,\s]*`

Comment: Thanks now i am getting [,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. The first element is empty string

Comment: I said: "First, you need to trim any commas at the beginning or end."